# react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I know the error. It says that I need to place a `key={object.id}` in the `map()` function of my code. I have that but the error still shows on the browser console. Any idea why this is happening?

```js
          <>
            <section className="bg-light py-5">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-lg-10">
                            <h1 className="post-archive-tag" >Recent Rants</h1>
                            {this.state.rants.map((rant) => (
                              <div key={rant.id} >
                            <Link className="post-archive-item" to={`/rant/${rant.slug}`}>
                                <h1>{ rant.title }</h1>
                            </Link>
                            {rant.categories.map((category) => (
                            <small className="post-archive-meta-details-name"><Link className="post-archive-meta-details-name text-dark font-weight-bold" to={`/category/${category.slug}`}>#{category.slug} </Link></small>
                            ))}                                                                   
                            <hr className="my-4" />
                            </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
          </>
```

Comment: `this.state.rants` you specify `key=" rant.id"`  is your id field unique?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the key `rant.id` you are providing is unique to the div element, as there are few chances that the looping is done in same sections with key as id so somehow the id gets duplicated if it is not mongo id.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify **unique** key on the first tag inside every map function.
I see you have two maps. One is mapping over `this.state.rants` and other is mapping over `rant.categories`.

So inside `rant.categories` also you need to add key prop for `<small className="post-archive-meta-details-name" key={SOMETHING UNIQUE}>`